# Dynamically generating numbered html based on how many elements are in a div

Tags: jquery, indexing

Basically I need to figure out a jQuery function that will count how many dd's there are and append one corresponding link with the appropriately numbered hash to the #external-navigation div.

The html structure should wind up like this:

```
<dl id="slider">
    <dd>
    </dd><!--slide one-->

    <dd>
    </dd><!--slide two-->

    <dd>
    </dd><!--slide three-->
</dl>

<div id="external-navigation">
    <a href="#1">Slide One</a>
    <a href="#2">Slide Two</a>
    <a href="#3">Slide Three</a>
</div>
```

I'm assuming this would use something like $('dd').each(function(i){ });...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track:

```
$('#slider dd').each(function(i,el) {
    var n = i+1;
    $('#external-navigation').append('<a href="#slide'+n+'">Slide '+n+'</a> ');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NNWsD/1/

http://api.jquery.com/each/

(You aren't supposed to start an ID with a number, and you shouldn't start a name with a number.)

Comment: `i` starts from `0`. So you have to change it to `(i + 1)` when concatenating `a` element.

Comment: Yesss. Thanks! :D

Follow up, if you're so inclined: The i,el that follows the function. What exactly is this specifying? What do?

Comment: `i` is current `index` and `el` is current `dom element` when `each` function iterates all matching elements.